# Why is it that the output of an "Image.network" call is not a future?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app which needs to get an image from the internet. For a split second, the whole MaterialApp loads but not the Image widget (I suppose it is loading the image). My question is: why is it that an "Image.network" call doesn't output a future?

Comment: 1. `Image.network` is a constructor, so it therefore must return an `Image`. 2. If `Image.network` were a `static` method that returned a `Future<Image>`, then it would be harder to use; you would, for example, need to combine it with a `FutureBuilder`. 3. If you'd rather handle it manually, you could issue the HTTP request yourself, `await` the response, and use `Image.memory` on the image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Image.network` call is not an `asynchronous` operation, it does not return a `Future`. `Image.network` makes an HTTP request to the server and then waits for a response when you call it. The main thread and the remainder of your code continue to run unhindered. When you use `Image.network`, the widget is made to load the picture silently in the background without interfering with the main thread.

You can use [`FadeInImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) widget or [`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package  to display a placeholder picture while the actual image is loading.